# Show that OA1 + OB1 + OC1 = OA + OB + OC using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry

Let O be the point inside triangle △ABC, and A1, B1, C1 are middle of the sides AB, BC, CD.

How can I prove that (using vectors):

**OA1** + **OB1** + **OC1** = **OA** + **OB** + **OC**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ be the position vectors of A,B,C  about O then PVs of A1,B1,C1 are $(\vec b +\vec c)/2,  (\vec a+ \vec c)/2, (\vec a+ \vec b)/2,$ respectively.
Then LHS is
$$LHS= (\vec b +\vec c)/2+(\vec a+ \vec c)/2+(\vec a+ \vec b)/2= \vec a+ \vec b +\vec c= RHS$$